# How can i make seperate phone numbers in php post forms?

Tags: php, forms, post, numbers, action

**Hi guys, i need little help! :)**

**Here is the example!
when ppl write phone box result that 55555555555, but when form submit/post that i want result like that 555-555-55-55 is there any example for it? thanks for help.**

```
<input type="text" id="phone" class="form-icon form-icon-phone" name="phone" data-required="" autocomplete="off" />
```

postform.php

```
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
```

**is there any example for it?**

Comment: You want `$phone` to become that? Can you describe the syntax you are trying to match, or define the pattern, e.g. a US phone number differs from a UK phone number, and a US phone number for some in the UK to use also differs.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/* formats a 11 or 7 digit phone number (number only) by 
adding dashes at the appropriate locations */
function phoneFormat($number) {
    if(ctype_digit($number) && strlen($number) == 11) {
    $number = substr($number, 0, 3) .'-'. substr($number, 3, 3) .'-'. substr($number, 6);
    } else {
        if(ctype_digit($number) && strlen($number) == 7) {
            $number = substr($number, 0, 3) .'-'. substr($number, 3, 4);
        }
    }
    return $number;
}
   ?>
```

Then use
    echo phoneFormat($_POST['phone']);

You can use this function and call it when you want to display the phone number

Comment: OP doesn't have a 7 or 10 digit phone number. I suspect these are international phone numbers.

Comment: This still won't give `555-555-55-55`.

Comment: that is for display but i want ppl enter normal phone number without any format like that -> 5555555555 and than wanna see in my database form posted and numbers convert to 555-555-55-55 something like that. i just want result with - in my database after they submit form thats all - thanks for help btw.